# Creating a set-builder notation with alternating negative and positive numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I'm working on a problem:
**"Convert the given set into a set in set-builder notation: $B = \{2, -5, 8, -11, 14, ...\}$."**

I found that for the pattern of number changing is going up by $3$ and alternating between negative and positive integers. Negative when $x$ is odd and positive when $x$ is even.

I've made this set-builder notation below for the changing by $3$.

$$\{x ∈ \mathbb Z | x\%3 - 2 = 0\}$$

What can I modify in the above set-builder notation to work with the alternating between positive and negative aspect.

Comment: These kinds of things usually involve a factor of $(-1)^n$

Comment: what does this mean: $x\%3 - 2 = 0\,$?

Comment: "x%3 - 2 = 0" is "(x modulo 3) - 2 = 0" or "xmod3 -2 = 0"
In this case, the remainder of x when divided by 3

Comment: I see. A mathematician might write instead $x-2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, or even more likely $x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$ In words "$x$ is congruent to $2$, modulo $3$".

Comment: @AlexS. As a programmer I'm quite familiar with % notation, but is this the notation you're being taught in discrete math? I only ask out of curiosity—I've never seen that notation used in mathematics.

Comment: @JackGallagher No, this notation is not being taught to me in discrete math, I am reviewing some discrete math topics online as it has been a few years since I took it as a class. You are right with mentioning your familiarity as a programmer, I code a lot so the % notation was my first go to in thinking of a solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what is your definition of "set-builder notation".

The set written by Kman3 is the correct set, although I would probably write it $$\{(-1)^{x-1}(3x-1)\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}},$$

where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Alternatively, if you want to stick with the modulo point of view in the set of all integers:

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\ | \ x>0,\,x\%6=2\}\,\cup\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\ | \ x<0,\,x\%6=1\}.$$

Or without the percent sign notation:

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\ | \ x>0,\,\,x \equiv 2 \pmod{6}\}\,\,\cup\,\,\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\ | \ x<0,\,\,x \equiv 1 \pmod{6}\}.$$

**Edit:**

If you don't want the union there ($\cup$), we can write:

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\ : \ |x| \equiv 2 \pmod{3},\quad\,x \equiv 1 \,\text{or}\,2 \pmod{6}\}$$

$$=\,\,\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\ : \ |x|\%3=2,\quad x\%6\in\{1,2\}\}.$$

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, because the sequence is alternating it would be best to have a $(-1)^n$ term which will vary the sign depending on the parity of $n$:

$$\{(-1)^{x-1}(3x-1) \ | \ x \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

is a possibility.

Comment: In set-builder notation, is the resulting set, in this case B = {2, -5, 8, -11, 14, ...}, based on the outcome values of the formula, $$\{(-1)^{x-1}(3x-1) \}$$ and not the values of x itself?

For example, if the set was just B = {2, 5, 8, 11, 14, ...} would {x∈N|x%3−2=0} have been an incorrect set-builder notation since there is no outcome for x%3−2=0 it just has specific x values that satisfy it?

Comment: @AlexS. I haven't seen that symbol used outside of computer programming. I suppose if you really wanted to use modulo, you could have the set $\{x \equiv -1 \pmod 3  \ | \  x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for simply the positive values.